# Is there a more efficient way to format this list

Tags: python

I have a list of coordinates, but I want to format them so they form a grid. Right now, for every element of the list, I'm checking what its value is and then formatting it. Is there a smarter, more efficient way to do this?

```
def convertDataToCoords(xCoords, yCoords):
    xSorted = []
    ySorted = []
 
    for y in yCoords:
        if y >= 0 and y <= 175:
            ySorted.append(150)
        elif y > 175 and y <= 275:
            ySorted.append(230)
        elif y > 275 and y <= 350:
            ySorted.append(310)
        elif y > 350 and y <= 450:
            ySorted.append(400)
        elif y > 450 and y <= 525:
            ySorted.append(480)
        elif y > 525  and y <= 600:
            ySorted.append(575)
        elif y > 600 and y <= 700:
            ySorted.append(650)
        elif y > 700 and y <= 775:
            ySorted.append(732.5)
        elif y > 775 and y <= 860:
            ySorted.append(830)
        elif y > 860 and y <= 950:
            ySorted.append(900)
        elif y > 950 and y <= 1050:
            ySorted.append(1000)
        else:
            ySorted.append(1090)

 
    for x in xCoords:
        if x >= 0 and x <= 150:
            xSorted.append(130)
        elif x > 150 and x <= 250:
            xSorted.append(230)
        elif x > 250 and x <= 350:
            xSorted.append(330)
        elif x > 350 and x <= 450:
            xSorted.append(430)
        elif x > 450 and x <= 550:
            xSorted.append(530)
        elif x > 550 and x <= 650:
            xSorted.append(630)
        elif x > 650 and x <= 750:
            xSorted.append(730)
        else: 
            xSorted.append(830)
```

Comment: make bins or chunks then apply append.

Comment: a dictionary with a minVal, maxVal and outputVal. Iterate over it to see where your value falls and assign the output value.

Comment: Do you intend your grid to have even spacing? Currently, your intervals vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `if-else` with the list of min, max and expected values:

```
X = [(0, 150, 130),
     (150, 250, 230),
     (250, 350, 330)]

Y = [(0, 175, 150),
     (175, 275, 230),
     (275, 350, 310)]


def convert(coords, items):
    result = []
    for coord in coords:
        for min_, max_, exp in items:
            if min_ < coord < max_:
                result.append(exp)
    return result


x_sorted = convert([100, 200, 300], X)
y_sorted = convert([50, 150, 250], Y)
```

Comment: That is a great improvement! Could even do `for min_, max_, exp in items:` which I think would make it even more explicit.

Comment: This is a really good solution, because I also want to be able to change what the min and max values are, so this solves that problem as well

Answer (score 0):

```
import math  

ymin=[-1, 175, 275, 350, 450, 525, 600, 700, 775, 860, 950, math.inf]
yapp=[  150, 230, 310, 400, 480, 575, 650, 732.5, 830, 900, 1000, 1090]
ymax=[175, 275, 350, 450, 525, 600, 700, 775, 860, 950, 1050,math.inf]
    
xmin=[-1, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, math.inf]
xapp=[  130, 230, 330, 430, 530, 630, 730, 830]
xman=[150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, math.inf]
      
def DataToCoord(xCoords, yCoords):
    xSorted = []
    ySorted = []
    
    for x,y in zip(xCoords, yCoords):
        yindex=-1+sum(1*(y > i) for i in ymin)
        xindex=-1+sum(1*(x > i) for i in xmin)
        ySorted.append(yapp[yindex])
        xSorted.append(xapp[xindex])
```

You do not need to check y<=ymax, because ymax is inside ymin

But if the numbers on ymax are not in ymin, you can do

```
import math

ymin=[-1, 175, 275, 350, 450, 525, 600, 700, 775, 860, 950, math.inf]
yapp=[  150, 230, 310, 400, 480, 575, 650, 732.5, 830, 900, 1000, 1090]
ymax=[175, 275, 350, 450, 525, 600, 700, 775, 860, 950, 1050,math.inf]
    
xmin=[-1, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, math.inf]
xapp=[  130, 230, 330, 430, 530, 630, 730, 830]
xman=[150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, math.inf]
    
def DataToCoord(xCoords, yCoords):
    xSorted = []
    ySorted = []

    for x,y in zip(xCoords, yCoords):
        ySorted.append(sum((y > i and y <= j) * k for i, j, k in zip(ymin, ymax, yapp)))
        xSorted.append(sum((x > i and x <= j) * k for i, j, k in zip(xmin, xman, xapp)))
```

This works, because a boolean evaluation like (y> zz) returns True or false, and when True is multiplied, behaves as 1, meanwhile False behaves as 0